Upload failures for Microsoft Teams Approvals app?
When attempting to upload a file to the Approvals app within Microsoft Teams (from New approval request -->Basic Request --> Add attachment), if I select OneDrive I get the error "Failed to create shareable link for [filename]" as per

...and if I select Upload from my computer I get the error "Failed to get site information for data storage" as per https://imgur.com/a/eKSoOZN
It doesn't appear to matter what file type or size is uploaded and occurs both on the Desktop and Web-based Teams app. Crucially, this only happens when working from home, from our company office the upload works fine, suggesting some of form of network or policy related issue, however there is very limited documentation available around what needs to be configured and where to resolve this, and the few other forum posts I've seen about either of these issues does not provide any actionable information.
We have firewall restrictions in place for our sharepoint site, but our VPN is setup to be allowed through on this, and we have no issues with uploading/ downloading OneDrive and Sharepoint files from home other than with the approvals app.
Any ideas?
